# how to compare my current time and date with db stored date

Tags: php, date

here i have stored two dates in db like start date as 2014-07-07 00:00:00 and end date as 2014-07-15 23:59:59. Now how can I check my current date between the two days

```
$date1 = '2014-07-07 00:00:00';
$date2 = '2014-07-15 23:59:59';

$now = new DateTime();
$current_time = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>
```

if date1 and date2 are retrieved from db and compare with current date it getting from server if it is between the two days it should be display end time from now.

Answer (score 1):

USE :

```
$date1 = '2014-07-07 00:00:00';
$date2 = '2014-07-15 23:59:59';

$cdate1 = new DateTime($date1);
$vdate1 = $cdate1->getTimestamp();

$cdate2 = new DateTime($date2);
$vdate2 = $cdate1->getTimestamp();
```

compare integers ($vdate1 and $vdate2) to each other

Result will be in seconds

**Enjoy :)**

---

Answer (score 1):

If the two dates are exactly in the same format, php allows string comparison.

So you can do the following:

```
if(strcmp($date1, $current_time) <= 0 and strcmp($date2, $current_time) > 0)
{
// The date is within the limits
}
```

`strcmp` is a safer function for string comparison

So, in your case, you could have the following:

```
<?php 
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proms"); // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
    $current_time =date("h:i:sa");
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM image");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        if(strcmp($row['start_date'],$current_time) <= 0 && strcmp($row['end_date'],$current_time) > 0) {
            // The date is within the limits
            echo "yes";
        }
    }

?>
```

`'start_date'` and `'end_date'` should be substituted with your fields' names.

Comment: how to $date1 and $date2 are i entered manually but in my db it was more then 100 how i loop that for those

Comment: It's the same comparison, just within a for/while loop, and putting in place of `$date1` and `$date2` the right variable name (e.g. `$data["date_start"]` and `$data["date_end"]`, where `$data` is the variable where you loaded the single row). I hope this helps! :)

Comment: `<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proms");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$current_time =date("h:i:sa");


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM image");




while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 /*foreach($row as $rows){*/
 if($row['start_date'] <= $current_time  || $row['end_date'] > $current_time)
{
// The date is within the limits
echo "yes";
}

/* }*/
}
?>`

Comment: for one i did this but more then one it now allowing

Answer (score 1):

Just as an Object Oriented style alternative you can create objects as instances of DateTime class, like these:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2014-07-07 00:00:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('2014-07-15 23:59:59');
$now = new DateTime();
```

then, following your logic, you can compare if `now` is before or after the other dates, like:

```
var_dump($date2 > $now);
```

or you can retrieve an instance of DateInterval interface with:

```
$now_interval_from_date1 = $date1->diff($now);
```

and then use the `format` method to know exactly the time/day/etc.. differences, like:

```
$now_interval_from_date1->format("%R%H hours")
```

**You can find the format params here:**
http://www.php.net/manual/it/dateinterval.format.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following to compare current time between two dates

```
$date1 = '2014-07-07 00:00:00';
$date2 = '2014-07-15 23:59:59';
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$date1TimeStamp = strtotime($date1);
$date2TimeStamp = strtotime($date2);
$nowTimeStamp = strtotime($now);

if($date1TimeStamp <= $nowTimeStamp || $date2TimeStamp >= $nowTimeStamp){
   $seconds_diff = $date2TimeStamp - $nowTimeStamp;
   $days = $seconds_diff/(3600*24);
}else
   echo 'No, out';
```

**Edited calculation, now it displays remaining days time from now to end date.**

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strtotime('now') > strtotime($date1) && strtotime('now') < strtotime($date2)) {
       $diff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime('now');
}
```

`$diff` then contains the difference between the two dates in miliseconds. Just convert miliseconds to days : hours : minutes (Mathematics ?)